# WPF Ellipse with BackgroundColor and Image

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone, fill, ellipse

I'm developing a Windows Phone application and I have some Ellipses. Is it possible to have a background image on them AND a background color?

When I looked for it, VS only allows me to change the Fill property with an image but didn't allow me to keep the Color on Fill + the Image.

Comment: Are you looking for an ellipse with a particular image with a background to cover the area the image doesn't cover?  Or something else. Describing your goal will help us direct you better.

Comment: @nekizalb Exactly. I have the Ellipse here, but I can only fill it either with a Color or with an Image (in the Fill property)

What I'm trying to do is keep the Color and an Image on that Ellipse!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use two ellipses, overlapping each other:

```
<Grid>
    <Ellipse Width="100" Height="60" Fill="Navy" />
    <Ellipse Width="100" Height="60">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <RadialGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="#00FF0000" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFF0000" Offset="1" />
            </RadialGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>
</Grid>
```

Change the fill property of the second to use your image.

Comment: Hey @Wonko it works! But is there no way to set both properties in the same control?

Comment: Nope - it's a single property on a single layer.  You could always create a custom composite control that allows you to create "BackgroundColor" and "Image" properties, but that control will have an implementation like this underneath.

Comment: Humm, I see! So, I'm using your answer now!! Thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
<Ellipse>
  <Ellipse.Fill>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/myimage.png" Stretch="Fill"></ImageBrush>
  </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```